# Removing the item being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I created a canvas and I can add objects. How can I remove the item clicked?

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  fill: 'green',
  width: 40,
  height: 80
});
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 20, 
  fill: 'red', 
  left: 100, 
  top: 100
});
canvas.add(rect);
canvas.add(circle);
```

Comment: [.remove()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Collection.html#remove), [Delete multiple Objects at once on a fabric.js canvas in html5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829786/delete-multiple-objects-at-once-on-a-fabric-js-canvas-in-html5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabric.js provides `object:selected` event on `canvas`. You can listen to this event and then remove the item it occurred on. Here's the sample code:

```
canvas.on('object:selected',function(ev){
    canvas.remove(ev.target);
});
```

You can read the [documentation](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#Canvas) and look at the jsfiddle i created here: http://jsfiddle.net/yrL4eLsn/1/

Comment: Thanks, can I do it to select two items?

Comment: Yes. you can use selection:created event which fires when multiple objects are selected. It returns an array of selected objects. You can loop over and remove them as you like.

Comment: I created multiple shapes(rectangle, triangle,circle..) in canvas.I want to select two same shapes and then remove selected two items when I click on second shape?

Comment: Did not understand what you meant. Can you create a fiddle for your problem? It will be easier.

Comment: I want to click and select first circle then I will click second circle. When I click second circle, circles should be deleted?  http://jsfiddle.net/yrL4eLsn/2/

Answer (score 0):

Please refer fabrics readme : fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-2/

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(options) {if (options.target){console.log('an object was clicked!',options.target.type);canvas.remove(options.target);}});

Posting code in single line as I am using a cellphone