# Let user delete a selected fabric js object

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have a simple fabric js based application where I will let users add shapes connect them and animate them.

Following is my JS

```
var canvas; 
window.newAnimation = function(){
   canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
}

window.addRect = function(){
    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  fill: 'red',
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
});
    canvas.add(rect);

}

window.addCircle = function(){
    var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 20, fill: 'green', left: 100, top: 100
});
    canvas.add(circle);
}
```

This is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wwerpuj9/). You can click on new animation and then add objects as of now.

I want the user to select some object and then also be able to delete it I am not sure how. I found this [Delete multiple Objects at once on a fabric.js canvas in html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829786/delete-multiple-objects-at-once-on-a-fabric-js-canvas-in-html5) But i was not able to implement it successfully. I basically want users to be able to select an object and delete it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Edit: This is for older versions now.

You can use the remove() method, eg.

```
window.deleteObject = function() {
        canvas.getActiveObject().remove();
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wwerpuj9/2/)

Comment: This answer is outdated and doesn't work for newer versions of Fabric.js check the answer of @AlexAndre here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46179274/1697459

Answer (score 94):

Since new version of fabric.js was released - you should use:

```
canvas.remove(canvas.getActiveObject());
```

Comment: This works only for one single object . What about multiple selected objects?

Comment: @rostamiani , just use `canvas.getActiveObjects();` and loop through them, calling canvas.remove() in the loop.

Something like:

`while (canvas.getActiveObjects.length > 0)
{
    canvas.remove(canvas.getActiveObject[0]);
}`

Comment: So when I call the canvas.remove(object) function, after the objects are deleted, it won't let me add new itext to the canvas.

Comment: It seems to work with `canvas.remove(...canvas.getActiveObjects());` or `canvas.getActiveObjects().forEach((obj) => {canvas.remove(obj);});`.
[JSDoc: Class: Canvas](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#remove)

Answer (score 25):

Delete all selected objects:

```js
canvas.getActiveObjects().forEach((obj) => {
  canvas.remove(obj)
});
canvas.discardActiveObject().renderAll()
```

Answer (score 7):

I am using Fabric JS 2.3.6.

I wanted to allow the user to select one or more objects on the canvas and delete them by clicking the delete button.

**Removed methods from old versions**

The following methods are no longer available since the introduction of ActiveSelection:

```
setActiveGroup(group);
getActiveGroup();
deactivateAll();
discardActiveGroup();
deactivateAllWithDispatch();
```

**Here is my code that works great for me and hopefully you as well.**

```
$('html').keyup(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 46) {
            deleteSelectedObjectsFromCanvas();
        }
});    

function deleteSelectedObjectsFromCanvas(){
    var selection = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (selection.type === 'activeSelection') {
        selection.forEachObject(function(element) {
            console.log(element);
            canvas.remove(element);
        });
    }
    else{
        canvas.remove(selection);
    }
    canvas.discardActiveObject();
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple actually.

Just use [Fabric's event handling](http:////fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-2#events) to manage the object selection, and then fire the delete function for whatever object is selected.

I'm using the canvas selection events to cover all the objects of the canvas. The idea is to add a delete button, keeping it hidden unless needed, and then handling its display on canvas selection events.

Deletion is made easy with the help of remove property of the Fabric library, which obviously triggers when the delete button is clicked.

Here is some sample code to demo what I said above.

```js
// Grab the required elements
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c'),
    delBtn = document.getElementById('delete')

// Hide the delete button until needed
delBtn.style.display = 'none'

// Initialize a rectangle object
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  fill: 'red',
  width: 100,
  height: 50
})

// Initialize a circle object
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  left: 250,
  top: 100,
  radius: 20,
  fill: 'purple'
})

// Add objects to the canvas
canvas.add(rect)
canvas.add(circle)

// When a selection is being made
canvas.on({
  'selection:created': () => {
    delBtn.style.display = 'inline-block'
  }
})

// When a selection is cleared
canvas.on({
  'selection:cleared': () => {
    delBtn.style.display = 'none'
  }
})

// Rmove the active object on clicking the delete button
delBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  canvas.remove(canvas.getActiveObject())
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #333;
}

#c {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>

<h4>Select an object</h4>

<canvas id="c" width="600" height="200"></canvas>

<input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete selection">
```

Easy, wasn't it? Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

On further improving @Rahul answer, we can also support deletion of selected object using key events like 'Delete', 'Backscape'.

```js
// Grab the required elements
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c'),
    delBtn = document.getElementById('delete'),
wrapper= document.getElementById('canvasWrapper')

// Hide the delete button until needed
delBtn.style.display = 'none'

// Initialize a rectangle object
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  fill: 'red',
  width: 100,
  height: 50
})

// Initialize a circle object
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  left: 250,
  top: 100,
  radius: 20,
  fill: 'purple'
})

// Add objects to the canvas
canvas.add(rect)
canvas.add(circle)

// When a selection is being made
canvas.on({
  'selection:created': () => {
    delBtn.style.display = 'inline-block'
  }
})

// When a selection is cleared
canvas.on({
  'selection:cleared': () => {
    delBtn.style.display = 'none'
  }
})

// Rmove the active object on clicking the delete button
delBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  canvas.remove(canvas.getActiveObject())
})

//Remove using keyboard events
wrapper.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
   if (
      e.keyCode == 46 ||
      e.key == 'Delete' ||
      e.code == 'Delete' ||
      e.key == 'Backspace'
    ) {
      if (canvas.getActiveObject()) {
        if (canvas.getActiveObject().isEditing) {
          return
        }
        canvas.remove(canvas.getActiveObject())
      }
    }
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #333;
}

#c {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>

<h4>Select an object</h4>
<div tabIndex="1000"id="canvasWrapper" @keyup="checkDelete($event)" >
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
<input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete selection">
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to handle selection of multiple objects. I think looping is needed as @venkystroke mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Delete object in Fabricjs. This works completely fine.

```
this.canvas.getActiveObjects().forEach((o) => {
    this.canvas.remove(o);
})
this.canvas.discardActiveObject() // Removes selection box
```

Answer (score 0):

you can delete active object by using backspace key

```
$(document).keydown(function(event){
    if (event.which == 8) {
        if (canvas.getActiveObject()) {
            canvas.getActiveObject().remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: outdated? this throws an error... it says there is no function called .remove().

Comment: can't you see when the answer has been posted it's been 1 year.if you are using latest version of fabric js then what's my fault.you should follow the official documentation of latest fabric js

please follow below link

http://fabricjs.com/v2-breaking-changes-2

Comment: Ah, yes. I can see the post date... just a thought tho... why does Larry Roberston's .remove() work, which is older than your code, or even Alex Andre's, which again is even older than your code. Nonetheless, thanks for the link to the docs, which is pretty useful.

Comment: 2019; why jQuery?  =)

Answer (score 0):

A much cleaner way to do it is to use the spread operator:

```
canvas.remove(...canvas.getActiveObjects())
```

The spread operator will pass each active object as a separate argument to the function.