# FabricJS Delete multiple object in V.2

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to select multiple and delete.  Selecting one object deletes just fine but when selecting multiple it doesn't do anything.  I have looked around and seen this answer with a fiddle which works in v1.4

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41286840

When I select multiple I get

```
canvas.getActiveGroup is not a function
```

Now as the getActiveObject can go from an array.  I tried to check if greater than one using length and then deleting those objects but it always goes through the

```
if (activeObject) {
```

instead of

```
else if (activeObject.length >= 2) {
```

But neither will work.  Doesn't Fabric have a function with multiple selected items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is mentioned on [change log](http://fabricjs.com/v2-breaking-changes-2) `getActiveGroup` this function is removed now.

So you need to get the object using `canvas.getActiveObjects()` then loop through the objects present and remove them from canvas.

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/durga598/z0qn35Lo/61/)

Comment: In that example I getUncaught TypeError: activeObject.forEachObject is not a function on single delete.  Multiple works just fine.  How would I check if object is multiple? I tried if (activeObject.length >= 2) {   and doesnt work

Comment: @ServerSideSkittles My bad, didnt check for single object. Check updated fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

**canvas.getActiveGroup** was removed in the new versions. so here's the code work fine. try this. more information about fabricJs changes click to refer this [fabricJS breaking changes](http://fabricjs.com/v2-breaking-changes-2)

```
deleteSelectedObject() {
    let activeObject = this.canvas.getActiveObjects();
    if (activeObject) {
      let objectsInGroup = activeObject;
      this.canvas.discardActiveObject();
      let self = this;
      objectsInGroup.forEach(function(object) {
        self.canvas.remove(object);
      });
    }
  }
```